# Check for multiple missing arguments in a call of an arbitrary function

Tags: r, arguments, rlang

Is there a conciser generic way to check for missing arguments in a function call via `rlang` functionality?

I don't like the `rlang::call_frame()$env %>% as.list()` part, but couldn't get anything to work by using, e.g. `rlang::fn_fmls()` or `rlang::call_args()`

```
library(magrittr)

foo <- function(a, b) {
  rlang::call_frame()$env %>% 
    as.list() %>% 
    purrr::map_lgl(rlang::is_missing)
}
foo()
#>    a    b 
#> TRUE TRUE
foo(1)
#>     a     b 
#> FALSE  TRUE
foo(1, 2)
#>     a     b 
#> FALSE FALSE
foo(b = 2)
#>     a     b 
#>  TRUE FALSE
```

Created on 2019-01-14 by the [reprex package](http://Created%20on%202019-01-14%20by%20the%20reprex%20package%20(v0.2.1)) (v0.2.1)

Answer (score 1):

You want `rlang::fn_fmls_syms()`, which returns the formal argument list as symbols. Pass those directly to `enexprs` via `do.call` to retrieve the user-supplied expressions for each argument:

```
foo <- function( a, b ) {
  do.call( rlang::enexprs, rlang::fn_fmls_syms() ) %>%
    purrr::map_lgl( rlang::is_missing )
}
```

Not sure if it's really any more concise than your original version. ;)